# Range ordering and inequality comparison

Tags: python-3.x, range, inequality

I was trying to recreate Python's [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) as a learning exercise, and noticed that ranges had `range.__gt__`, `range.__ge__` etc. attribute. It was specifically defined in range, as range also has 8 attributes with the qualified name of `object.__...__`.

I was wondering what the range comparisons are used for. Any attempt at `range(*x) <= range(*y)` raises a `TypeError: unorderable types: range() > range()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python 3 range object defines the following rich comparisons (taken from the [C source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f3dbeca1e30d/Objects/rangeobject.c#l471)):

```c
static PyObject *
range_richcompare(PyObject *self, PyObject *other, int op)
{
    int result;
    if (!PyRange_Check(other))
        Py_RETURN_NOTIMPLEMENTED;
    switch (op) {
    case Py_NE:
    case Py_EQ:
        result = range_equals((rangeobject*)self, (rangeobject*)other);
        if (result == -1)
            return NULL;
        if (op == Py_NE)
            result = !result;
        if (result)
            Py_RETURN_TRUE;
        else
            Py_RETURN_FALSE;
    case Py_LE:
    case Py_GE:
    case Py_LT:
    case Py_GT:
        Py_RETURN_NOTIMPLEMENTED;
    default:
        PyErr_BadArgument();
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the only comparisons that are actually implemented are `NE` and `EQ` which are for inequality and equality. The other comparisons, like larger-equals, larger-than, etc., are all `Py_RETURN_NOTIMPLEMENTED`, so while they are “technically” implemented (as in the builtin object defines the comparison methods), they throw a NotImplementedError.

Comment: If this is the case, what will they be (or are planned to be) used for?

Comment: They are not used for anything. It’s just how built-in objects have to be implemented. In order to support (any) comparison methods, they need to have a richcompare function; and the side effect is that you get the other ones too which you my need to disable explicitely. See also [`PyTypeObject.tp_richcompare`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html?#c.PyTypeObject.tp_richcompare).